# how to create an apk file from gradle script

Tags: android

How to create an anpk file using gradle script.I have one android project.I want to create its apk but using gradle script not through android studio.
Is there any such script which will create apk.

Comment: did you try `gradle build` ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use gradlew script to build your apk file. Gradlew script is part of the project which is created using Android Studio. You can run gradle script like this

```
gradlew assembleDebug
```

or

```
gradlew assembleRelease
```

first option will generate apk in debug configuration. Second will generate release APK. There is also several other things that you need to prepare before you run this script. The most important thing is that you need to create keystore and point it in your gradle file.

To create keystore you can use this command:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore keystore.jks -alias your-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

keytool should be placed in bin folder in your java root directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you run `gradle tasks` you will see available task for your project. Here is the `Build section`

```
Build tasks
-----------
assemble - Assembles all variants of all applications and secondary packages.
assembleAndroidTest - Assembles all the Test applications.
assembleDebug - Assembles all Debug builds.
assembleDebugAndroidTest - Assembles the android (on device) tests for the Debug build.
assembleRelease - Assembles all Release builds.
build - Assembles and tests this project.
buildDependents - Assembles and tests this project and all projects that depend on it.
buildNeeded - Assembles and tests this project and all projects it depends on.
clean - Deletes the build directory.
compileDebugAndroidTestSources
compileDebugSources
compileDebugUnitTestSources
compileReleaseSources
compileReleaseUnitTestSources
mockableAndroidJar - Creates a version of android.jar that's suitable for unit tests.
```

So

```
gradle build
```

should do the job

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own script using available gradle commands.
[Here](https://medium.com/@mayuri.k18/how-to-quickly-build-and-run-android-apks-using-an-automated-script-eb0e4a997d68) is a detailed article for build, test and deploy via bash script.

Following is the sample script you can use.

```
enter code 
#Define all paths, constants here
PROJECT_DIR='/Users/mayuri/CODE/AndroidBuildAutomationSample/'
OUTPUT_DIR='/Users/mayuri/CODE/AndroidBuildAutomationSample/OUTPUT_DIR/'

#Enter project dir
cd $PROJECT_DIR

#Start Build Process
echo "\n\n\nCleaning...\n"
./gradlew clean

echo "\n\n\ncleanBuildCache...\n"
./gradlew cleanBuildCache

echo "\n\n\n build...\n"
./gradlew build

echo "\n\n\n assembleDebug...\n"
./gradlew assembleDebug

#Install APK on device / emulator
echo "installDebug...\n"
./gradlew installDebug
```

Remember to give execute permissions to your script file

```
chmod +x automate.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following commands from the directory of the associated project.

```
# build project, runs both the assemble and check task
gradle build


# build project complete from scratch
gradle clean build


# speedup second grandle build by holding it in memory
gradle build --daemon
```

By default, the Gradle build creates two .apk files in the build/outputs/apk folder. Check this [link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBuild/article.html) for further information
.

Comment: I am creating a script file,where it will download the android sdk,gradle,install them,checkout project from github and then create apk using gradle.So that I dont hv to be dependant on installation of android sdk,gradle on my system.I just need to run my script and it will generate the apk.

Comment: refer to this link...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32965204/how-to-build-and-run-android-apk-on-emulator-using-dockerfile